# iOS 8.3 UiAlertView close apple keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, ios8.3

I upgraded my iPhone version from 8.2 to 8.3 today and saw that apple changed the keyboard behaviour. when I show `UIAlertVIew` the keyboard close automatically.

I need to keep the keyboard open. Is that possible?

Comment: This may be an attempt to get you to switch to the `UIAlertController` by introducing changes in behavior for deprecated APIs

Comment: Use `UIAlertController`

Comment: UIAlertController doesn't solve the problem , apple keyboard still close when the alerts show.

Comment: If there's no textfield in the alert, you can put a call `[textfield becomeFirstResponder]` after the `[alert show]` which should keep it open - where textfield is the active textfield prior to popping up the dialog. If you *have* a textfield, it should pop-up again. There will be a brief flash as the text field pops down then back up again, though

Comment: `UIAlertView` in iOS 8.3 behaves as `UIAlertController` does in iOS 8.0 and above. `UIAlertController` hides the keyboard. Most likely Apple is now using `UIAlertController` behind the scenes for it's implementation of `UIAlertView`.

Comment: This explains a new bug I'm seeing.  If I show one UIAlertView, then another after that, not only does the keyboard reopen for the 2nd one (hides for 1st), the keyboard is in front of the UIAlertView, so you can't tap the OK button.. but you also can't do anything with the keyboard (I have a Done button I add as input accessory, and it doesn't work, nor does Enter/Done on keyboard).  Guess it's time to rewrite my code :(

Answer (score 1):

To workaround this bug in iOS 8.

Whenever you dismiss your alert by clicking any button just call  `[textfield becomeFirstResponder]`. It will open the keyboard.

Or you can call `[textfield becomeFirstResponder]` after you do `[alert show]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the keyboard to be open after showing the alert, just use the following code:

Swift:

```
alert.show()
text1.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Objective-C:

```
[alert show];
[text1 becomeFirstResponder];
```